# Google Cloud Dataflow: 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Any suggestions on how to work around this error beside reducing the number of transformations in the flow (or, likely, reducing total serialized size of all transformation objects in flow graph)?

Thanks,

Comment: `dataflowJobFile` options creates job spec file ~ 2.3Mb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataflow currently has a limitation in our system that caps requests at 1MB. The size of the job is specifically tied to the JSON representation of the pipeline; a larger pipeline means a larger request.

We are working on increasing this limit. In the meantime, you can work around this limitation by breaking your job into smaller jobs so that each job description takes less than 1MB

To estimate the size of your request run your pipeline with the option

```
--dataflowJobFile = <path to output file>
```

This will write a JSON representation of your job to a file. The size of that file is a good estimate of size of the request. The actual size of the request will be slightly larger due to additional information that is part of the request.

Thank you for your patience.

We will update this thread once the limit has been increased.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of errors usually come up when your bundle batch size for ingestion is over limitation (20MB).

I'm not sure if you're using WriteToBigQuery. If you're not, feel free to ignore this answer. I usually get solved by trying one of these 2 solutions:

1. Solution1: Set **batch_size** of WriteToBigQuery to the number lower than 500. The Default is 500.
2. Solution2: Set **method** of WriteToBigQuery to `"FILE_LOADS"`, and also set other necessary parameters, such as **triggering_frequency** and **custom_gcs_temp_location**.
3. If above 2 solutions cannot solve your problem or are not suitable for your case, you have to make the granularity of each row smaller, so that the size of each row becomes smaller. This will need to modify parsing logic and BigQuery table schema.

To see the detail of parameters, please see the reference link.

Reference:

- https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.39.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery
- https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#json-request-too-large

Answer (score 0):

Are you serializing a large amount of data as part of your pipeline specification? For example, are you using the [Create Transform](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/Create) to create PCollections from inlined data?

Could you possible share the json file? If you don't want to share it publicly you could email it privately to the Dataflow team.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've sent the generated json file by email to the dataflow team. Regarding your questions, a) see my comment to the original question, b) No, but does it make any difference what type of data is being serialized?

Answer (score 0):

This has been merged into Beam on Nov, 16 2018. It should not be too much longer before this is included in Dataflow.